# One Cell number to compare in multiple rows

Tags: comparison

I have ID in Col A and Remarks in Col B. I need to Return status in Col C.

If Remarks against any specific ID is all Approved, it should show in status as "Approved".

If All remarks against one ID are not Approved it should show me in Remarks as "Not Approved" :

[image: Excel file]

Comment: can u please share a sample of expected output for each cell ?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution using auxiliar columns. I understand from your question that you want a third column to show only 2 status Approved and No approved, based on the composition if all the remarks are approved or not.
FYI: You will need to edit the formulas accordingly to your needs.

[image]

AUX1 =`=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$13;A2)`

AUX2 =`=A2&B2`

AUX3 =`=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$13;A2;$B$2:$B$13;B2)`

STATUS = `=IF(E6<>C6;"Not Approved";"Approved")`

This works by counting the IDs, then making an auxiliar name with the ID and the status, then count that and compare with the count for the ID. If there is a difference then its not approved.

For the sake of time I referenced a cell the "approved status" which you be better if you reference the status from within a hidden sheet.

Cheers.